# get the uploaded form data using jquery

Tags: jquery

how to get the details of form before post in the following way,
 or at least the details of the file(name, size etc..)

```
{"photo":{"name":"Vishnuvardhan.Siddareddy@fisglobal.com_F16.pdf","type":"application\/pdf","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpGHoRhJ","error":0,"size":72057}}
```

if i do alert(formdata), it is showing [object formdata].

jquery code

```
 $("#applyBtn").click(function(){
            var formObj = $('#multiform');
            var formURL = formObj.attr("action");           
            var formData = new FormData(this);

                alert(formData);
                return false;

            $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  formData,
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                    }           
               });
                e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the ID of your file, you can get all of it's pertinent info, using `getElementById` then taking that element's files property and parsing it.  Assuming you are only uploading one file, you will want files[0].

**HTML:**

```
<input type='file' onchange='get_info()' id = 'the_file' />
```

**Javascript:**

```
get_info = function(){
    the_file = document.getElementById('the_file');
    console.log(the_file.files[0]);
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/8pvhnfz9/

I'll go ahead and let you do the work of putting it into the object format you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormData` interface has no methods for getting data out of it, so you need to pull your data from the `this` object, before constructing the `FormData` object.